# Is keeping server in same region where are the users increase speed of site/application

Tags: webserver

It seems to be a dumb question, but i have to answer this question to my boss and i do not know what should i tell him?

Right now our servers are in US but 90% of our users are from India.
So my question is if we keep our sever in India then will we get better application/site speed?

Please share your thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure if the Connection doesnt goes around the world, you can use [treaceroute](http://networking.ringofsaturn.com/IP/traceroutedoc.php) the connection between client and server to see how many nodes are there and where are they located and compare both results.

Comment: Just FYI: You should not bug people about voting/accepting your answers.

Comment: Did you just changed the Votes in the Threads title from Votes to Votes/Accept, r u ok??